# changing box color with increment number or decrement number with jquery slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, colors, jquery-ui-slider

I am a beginner of jQuery, and wondered if anyone can point me to the right direction. I wanted to create a slider where it changes color from red to green, and scores will be recorded. The value should start at 0, and as user slides to the right, the color turns red, and score of -1 is recorded. If it slides to the left, the color turns green and score of +1 is recorded. Please help.

JS:

```
$(function(){
   $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:0,
      min: -3,
      max: 3,
      step: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $( "#score" ).val( ui.value );
      }
   });
   $( "#score" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Html:

```
<html>
<p>
  <label for="score">Rating (+/-1 increment):</label>
  <input type="text" id="score" />
</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: what did you try and what are you struggling with? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553

Comment: I have successfully getting the input out, but however, I am stuck at putting the color in it, where it will change color. For example, I slide to the left, my input text will show -1, but I am stuck at putting the code in to change the color to red, so I wondered how do i do it. Thanks for pointers and help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show your existing code, and perhaps set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Thank you all for responding. I am not sure how to add the UI in jsfiddle.net, it doesn't seem able to display the slider. Here's my code:-

<script>
$(function(){
$( "#slider" ).slider({
 value:0,
 min: -3,
 max: 3,
 step: 1,
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $( "#score" ).val( ui.value );
  }
 });
$( "#score" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

</script>




<html>
<p>
<label for="score">Rating (+/-1 increment):</label>
<input type="text" id="score" />
</p>
<div id="slider"></div>
</html>

Comment: A fiddle needs to include appropriate CSS info (I've included the base jquery-ui.css for you): http://jsfiddle.net/UweCD/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that setting the "background" CSS property does it. Is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/UweCD/1/

```
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#score").val(ui.value);
        $(this).css("background", ui.value>0 ? "green" : ui.value<0 ? "red" : "");
    }
```

Should be enough to get you started anyway...

Comment: Thank you sir/madam! This is what I need. It definitely get me started. Thank you so much!